# Can `in` operator in Python be used other than checking for membership in a sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.5

`in` operator in Python is a membership operator that tests for membership in a sequence.

**Description of `in` operator**

> Evaluates to true if it finds a variable in the specified sequence and false otherwise.

Now consider the code:

```
>>>s = 'HELLO'
>>>char = 'M'
>>>char in s
False
>>>for char in s:
....    print(char)
H
E
L
L
O
```

Please correct me here:
I think the statement `for char in s` should check for `'M'` in `'HELLO'` which should be evaluated to `False` and the loop should be terminated. But here, instead of checking for the membership, it is assigning every character to the variable `char` and thus the loop is printing the every character.
My question is, how `in` operator can be used other than checking the membership?

Comment: The main thing you need to think here is that the keyword `n` if you use it in for then it'll redefine char or every line in the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `in` keyword is used in two different contexts:

- Membership test
- Iteration

The first, as you said, checks if something belongs to a sequence, by calling that sequence's [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__). When using this syntax, a boolean value is returned.

```
x = 1
l = [0, 1, 2]
if x in l:
    print("x is in l")
else:
    print("x is not in l")
```

```
> x is in l
```

Since `in` looks for the `__contains__` method, `x in seq` is valid as long as `seq` implements a `__contains__` method. You can implement this, even though it does not make logical sense, regarding the concept of membership.

```
class Foo:
    def __contains__(self, x):
        return x == 12

f = Foo()
if 12 in f:
    print("12 is in f")
```

```
> 12 is in f
```

---

The second is actually more often used. According to an [iteration protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement), it enumerates the elements of an iterable object, so that actions can be performed on them.

You can iterate over a list:

```
l = [0, 1, 2]
for x in l:
    print(x)
```

```
> 0
> 1
> 2
```

Over a string:

```
s = "hello"
for c in s:
    print(c)
```

```
> h
> e
> l
> l
> o
```

And over any object implementing the [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) method, as long as the latter returns an object that implements the [`__next__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) method.

The following example is a basic (not to say "poor") `range`-like class, whose you can iterate over the instances.

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.current = first

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current == self.last:
            raise StopIteration
        result = self.current
        self.current += 1
        return result

b = Bar(0, 5)
for i in b:
    print(i)
```

```
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
```

A lot of native types are iterable: [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict), [ranges](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)...

---

Semantically speaking, it makes sense to use the same `in` word for both contexts. "Is this thing in that stuff?" is a valid question, as long as "stuff" is a collection, which is capable of containing things. Henceforth, "do this for every thing in that stuff" seems pretty natural.

Hence the use of "in" for both contexts.

This is however quite a simplification of the reality, which is actually more vast. I invite you to read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html), and for an in-depth understanding of the `in` keyword, read [Python's grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html).

Answer (score 0):

any object that has the __contains__() method can use the "in" operator. by using the dir() function or the hasattr() function you can check if you can use the "in" operator on that object

```
>>>dir(hw)
[...,__contains__,...]
>>>hasattr(hw,"__contains__")
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you need to think here is that the keyword `in` if you use it in a `for` loop then it'll redefine char or every line in the loop.

so to test every character individually in a loop you'd need:

```
s = 'HELLO'
char = 'M'
for chr in s:
    if char in chr:
        print chr
```

but that's kind of pointless. You might as well use `if char=chr`

But you can test for characters in list elements like this so:

```
s = ['HELLO', 'MIKE', 'BOB']
char = 'M'
for word in s:
    if char in word:
        print word
```

would test every list element for the presence of "M"

Comment: did you mean `if chr in char:` in the next-to last line of your second example or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: char is "M", chr is element in the list, so it's the right way round,

Comment: I'll rename those variables to make more sense